Optimizing Raspberry Pi 4B as a Wi-Fi Bridge to Avoid High Costs
I’m heading to a place where Wi-Fi usage is billed by the minute per MAC address. This means I can connect one device for unlimited minutes at a high cost. Adding more devices like phones, laptops, and tablets quickly increases the total cost.
To manage this, I’ve set up a Raspberry Pi 4B with a USB wireless NIC to create a second wireless interface. My plan is to connect the Raspberry Pi to the internet using one interface (wlan1) and broadcast a new wireless network on the other (wlan0). This way, all my personal devices can connect to the Raspberry Pi's network, using only one MAC address for billing purposes. (I am also aware that this might violate the network's use policy.)
I’ve created a prototype by enabling net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 and configuring iptables rules. During testing, I noticed a discrepancy in network throughput.
Setup:

PC: Connected to the internet (wlan1) running an iperf3 server
Raspberry Pi: Acting as both an iperf3 client/server
iPhone: Connected to the Raspberry Pi's hotspot (wlan0) running an iperf3 client

Test Results:

PC to Raspberry Pi: Full adapter speed (~60Mbps)
Raspberry Pi to iPhone: Full adapter speed (~60Mbps)
PC to iPhone via Raspberry Pi: Speed drops by a third to around 20Mbps

Question:
How can I optimize my setup to minimize the drop in network speed when routing between the two networks?
Troubleshooting Steps and Information:
Wireless Interface Details:
iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr dc:a6:32:3d:bb:23
        ssid HOTSPOT
        type AP
        wiphy 0
        channel 48 (5240 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 5240 MHz
        txpower 31.00 dBm

iw wlan1 info
Interface wlan1
        ifindex 4
        wdev 0x100000001
        addr 00:24:a5:9c:03:76
        ssid INTERNET
        type managed
        wiphy 1
        channel 36 (5180 MHz), width: 40 MHz, center1: 5190 MHz
        txpower 23.00 dBm

CPU and Memory Usage:
Running top during a speed test shows low CPU usage (97.8% idle). Memory usage is also low, with plenty of free RAM available.

iptables Configuration:
iptables -t nat -L -v -n && iptables -L -v -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1381 packets, 424K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 287 packets, 21682 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 131 packets, 10414 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 977 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  122  8883 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      wlan1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 926 packets, 104K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  606  117K ACCEPT     0    --  wlan0  wlan1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  615  402K ACCEPT     0    --  wlan1  wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 571 packets, 55940 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Additional Information:
The Raspberry Pi is powered with a 5V 3A adapter.
No other devices are connected except the WNIC and a cooling fan. Speed test results are consistent with the fan on and off.
I look forward to your suggestions and please let me know if you need more details or command outputs.
O

Remember that WiFi is half-duplex, and the iPhone-to-PC test is two radio hops, so it never will be as fast as the single-hop links.

You're probably better off using a "travel router" for what you want to do. There's plenty of cheap ones (less than the cost of a pi4 + case + sdcard + power supply) that will outperform the crappy onboard wifi + usb wifi combination you are using

Another alternative: the Pixel phones (at least the 6a, 6 Pro and 8a, but probably everything after 6a) could run a hotspot while connected to an existing WiFi network. The hotspot's traffic is sent to the existing network. That's what I use when I go to places like hotels or airports where the public WiFi might be restricted to one device per person (or room no. or phone no.). I don't have a new iPhone to test, but if it has the same capability, you might not have to carry around an extra device. And also Android phones have had USB tethering since forever (not sure about iPhones).
